# Certificate validation doesn't use proxy settings for chaintrust

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, certificate, x509certificate

I've been struggling to get a WCF client to work through a web proxy.  If I manually specify the proxy as below, I can get the http request to work.

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://x.x.x.x:3128", false);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```

However I have the client service proxy set to use `ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;`

Inspecting the packets that get sent out, the client successfully connects to the server, but the then tries to validate the certificate that the service provides.  This validation attempt fails because the requests for the chain do not have Proxy-Authorization headers (they fail with 407 errors).  How can I get these requests to properly use the DefaultWebProxy that's specified?

If I set the validation mode to None, then it all works of course, but I really don't want to have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

this setting only affects message level certificates. for transport level try something like this http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2008/12/wcf-gotcha-disabling-ssl-validation.html

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything on the transport level.  The issue here is that the validation is failing due to the validator being unable to reach the certificate servers.  For some unknown reason the validator is ignoring the proxy, when it should be using it.