# WCF service call from class project with proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, ssl, proxy

I need to make a WCF service call to an external 3rd party using 2-way SSL from a class project. I have added the WSDL provided by the 3rd party to my project as a Service Reference. The problem is that all calls outside our domain (*.abc.com) pass through a proxy server

```
http://ironport:8080
```

This is what I have done in my code -

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
binding.AllowCookies = false;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://blablabla.com/GetData.svc");
var client = new AccountClient(binding, endpoint);
X509Certificate2 certi = new X509Certificate2(@"path to pfx file", "password");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certi;
```

I make the service call using -

```
var account = client.ExportAccounts(obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

It then gives me an error -

```
The remote server returned an Error (407): Proxy authentication required
```

That is but obvious because nowhere did I mention the proxy details the request needs to go through. What I need is a way to add the following info from a web.config file of a different project into my request above -

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="http://ironport:8080" />
  <bypasslist>
    <add address="[\w]+\.abc\.com$" />
  </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Is there some way to achieve this in code? Or do I need to go about this in a different way altogether? Let me know if I need to post more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [WebProxy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Not tested, but something like this:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://ironport:8080");
proxy.BypassList = new string[] { "[\w]+\.abc\.com$" };
```

Another alternative would be to move the relevant section of the config to the web/app.config of the application that is using your class library.

**ADDED**

Not 100% sure this will work, but you could try adding this line to your code:

```
WebRequest.DefaultProxy = proxy;
```

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906054/getting-wshttpbinding-working-through-an-http-proxy)

Another option might be to use the `ProxyAddress` property of `WsHttpBinding` (make sure in that case you set the `UseDefaultProxy` to false), but I don't see a way to add a bypass list with this one.

Comment: Thanks. I can create a proxy object and populate it with my proxy data but I am unable to associate it in any which way to my service call -

`var client = new AccountClient(binding, endpoint);
var account = client.ExportAccounts(obj1, obj2, obj3);`

The AccountClient class takes in the binding and endpoint objects. No idea where to add the proxy object to.

Comment: @HimadriMishra - See my edit to see if either of these options help.

Comment: Thanks I can add the proxy details using the `ProxyAddress` property of `WsHttpBinding`.